# Meteor error: "com.meteor.webapp.WebAppException: Error parsing asset manifest"

Tags: cordova, meteor, build, angular-meteor

I have an error when i run my app in my android device with:

```
meteor run android-device --settings settings.json --mobile-server=myip:port
```

I have deployed my app in my VPS with MUP (Meteor up). The app in my device seems work good and is able to communicate with my VPS but i have this error:

> I20160516-20:17:03.059(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915): Download failure
>   I20160516-20:17:03.059(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):
>   com.meteor.webapp.WebAppException: Error parsing asset manifest
>   I20160516-20:17:03.060(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   com.meteor.webapp.AssetManifest.(AssetManifest.java:80)
>   I20160516-20:17:03.060(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   com.meteor.webapp.AssetBundleManager$1.onResponse(AssetBundleManager.java:112)
>   I20160516-20:17:03.060(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
>   I20160516-20:17:03.061(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>   I20160516-20:17:03.061(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   I20160516-20:17:03.061(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   I20160516-20:17:03.062(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) I20160516-20:17:03.062(2)?
>   W/MeteorWebApp( 3915): Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value
>   (JSONObject.java:160)
>   I20160516-20:17:03.063(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
>   I20160516-20:17:03.063(2)? W/MeteorWebApp( 3915):     at
>   com.meteor.webapp.AssetManifest.(AssetManifest.java:39)

I don't understand why i have this error. When i run the app in local without --mobile-server=myip:port, this error is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the hot code push failing due to the cordova manifest not being present. To confirm, visit `http://myip:port/__cordova/manifest.json` which should return a json document similar to `http://myip:port/manifest.json` (non-cordova). If you get your application/html page from the cordova url instead, this means your build didn't include the mobile platform (did you remove them before building?)

UPDATE: you also need to make sure to include `mobileSettings` and likely `serverOnly` in your mup.js config. See `lib/modules/meteor/build.js` in mup for reference to those options.

Comment: denis-babineau: could you please share your mup.json file? I'm having same issue and a working mobile-friendly mup.json may help.